# How does auto deduce type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some cases of use of `auto`:

```
auto s = expr;          //s is always lvalue
auto & s = expr;        //s is always lvalue reference? What if expr is rvalue?
auto && s = expr;       //s is perfectly forwarded
```

Are they true? If not, why?

Comment: The type deduced for `auto` in the declaration of a variable is defined via the rules of template argument deduction, see [dcl.spec.auto]/6; with one exception: if the initializer is a braced-init-list, the deduced type is a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Btw, `s` as an expression is *always* an lvalue, as `s` is an identifier (and no enumerator). lvalue/rvalue are categories of expressions.

Comment: P.S. This is *also* covered by [Scott Meyer's Universal Reference article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) ;)

Comment: @dyp He mentioned that `Widget&& var1 = somewidget; Widget& var2 = var1;` will make `var2` a type of `Widget&`. But which object does `var2` reference to? Isn't `var1` an rvalue reference? How can a lvalue reference bind to rvalue?

Comment: @dyp I think I got it now. `var1` is considered a lvalue...

Comment: Exactly :) All identifiers but enumerators are, as expressions, lvalues. Otherwise, you could move them twice implicitly: `Widget w1 = var1; Widget w2 = var1;`

Comment: @dyp What if I have something like this: `auto &var1 = someWidget`? Is it legal and how does a lvalue reference bind to a rvalue?

Comment: If that `someWidget` is an rvalue of type `Widget`, i.e. not an identifier.. rather something like `makeWidget()`, it will simply fail (it's ill-formed). If `someWidget` is a non-const rvalue, I understand `auto` is simply deduced to `Widget`, so the declaration becomes `Widget& s = someWidget`. What happens if `someWidget` is a const rvalue, I don't quite understand yet. Somehow the constness is dropped so that `auto` is also deduced to `Widget`, not `Widget const`, and it fails just like in the non-const case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dyp is correct and I would like to elaborate.

First of all, the conclusion is the from dyp:

> The type deduced for `auto` in the declaration of a variable is defined
>   via the rules of template argument deduction, see [dcl.spec.auto]/6;
>   with one exception: if the initializer is a braced-init-list, the
>   deduced type is a `std::initializer_list`.

I'll explain.

First,

```
auto s = expr;
```

This is same as deducing the `T` from `expr`,

```
template<class T>
void f(T s);

f(expr);
```

The rule for template argument deduction is quite complicated, since you are only concerning with the lvalue and rvalue stuff, let's focus on this.

Template argument deduction is by comparing the template parameter type (call it `P`, in this case `P` is `T`), and the corresponding argument (call it `A`, in this case, the type of `expr`).

From 14.8.2.1,

> If P is not a reference type:
>
> — If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is
>   used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> — If A is a function type, the pointer type produced by the function-to-pointer standard conversion (4.3)
>   is used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> — If A is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of A’s type are ignored for type deduction.

So, if `expr` is array or function, it will be treated as pointers, if expr has cv-qualification (`const` etc), they will be ignored.

> If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `P`’s type are ignored for type deduction.

This actually says:

```
const auto s = expr;
```

`s` is a `const` variable, but for type deduction for `auto` purposes, the `const` will be removed.

Thus, from the above rules, `auto` will be deduced to the type of `expr` (after some type conversion stated above).

Note that, when an expression is a reference to `T`, it will be adjusted to `T` before prior analysis.

So whatever `expr` is – rvalue, lvalue, or lvalue/rvalue ref type – the type of `auto` will always be the type of `expr` without reference.

```
auto s1 = 1; //int
int &x = s1;
auto s2 = x; //int
int &&y = 2;
auto s3 = y; //int
```

Second, let's look at

```
auto &s = expr;
```

This will be same as

```
template<class T>
void f(T &s);

f(expr);
```

The extra rule from standard is as follows:

> If `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction.

So the deduction of auto will be exactly same as without `&`, but after the `auto` type is deducted, the `&` is added to the end of `auto`.

```
//auto &s1 = 1; //auto is deducted to int, int &s1 = 1, error!
const auto &s1 = 1; //auto is deducted to int, const int &s1 = 1; ok!
const int &x = s1;
auto &s2 = x; //auto is int, int &s2 = x; ok!
int &&y = 2;
auto &s3 = y; //auto is int, int &s3 = y; ok!
```

Note that the last `y` is an lvalue. The rule of C++ is: named rvalue reference is an lvalue.

Lastly:

```
auto &&s = expr;
```

This is no doubt same as

```
template<class T>
void f(T &&s);

f(expr);
```

One additional rule from standard:

> If `P` is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and
>   the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in
>   place of `A` for type deduction.

This actually says that, if `expr` is an rvalue, the rule will be same as the second case (lvalue case), but if `expr` is an lvalue, the type of `A` will be an lvalue reference to `A`.

Note from previous explained, `A` is never reference, because the type of an expression is never a reference. But for this special case (`auto &&`, and `A` is an lvalue), reference to `A` must be used, regardless `expr` itself is a reference type or not.

Example:

```
auto &&s1 = 1; //auto is deducted to int, int &&s1 = 1, ok!
int x = 1;
auto &&s2 = x; //x is lvalue, so A is int &, auto is deducted to int &, int & &&s2 = x; ok!
int &&y = 2;
auto &&s3 = y; //y is lvalue, auto is int &, int & &&s3 = y; ok!
```

Comment: One last point I've been confused with: `auto& = makeSomething();`, with `sometype makeSomething();`: If `sometype` is non-const non-ref, this will fail as `auto` is deduced to `sometype` and `sometype& = makeSomething();` tries to bind a prvalue to an lvalue ref. If `sometype` const (no ref), but non-class non-array, the constness will be dropped according to [expr]/6 and the same happens. If `sometype` is a const class type (`using sometype = myclass const;`), then this will work as `auto` is deduced to `sometype const` (and `sometype const& s = makeSomething();` is legal).

Comment: using and typedef will not define new types, your example won't be legal because auto will be deduced to myclass, while not sometype.

Comment: Oops, that's a typo :) It should have been: If `sometype` is a const class type, e.g. `using sometype = myclass const;`, then this will work as `auto` is deduced to `myclass const` (and `myclass const& s = makeSomething();` is legal). (Btw: `sometype const` would just be redundant and equivalent to `sometype`)

Answer (score 0):

Since no one gives an answer and I kinda understand now (thanks to @dyp), I would just post answer myself. Point out error if any:

```
auto s = expr;
```

If `expr` is lvalue, prvalue, or any reference, `s` is always a lvalue and a copy is made.

```
auto& s = expr;
```

If `expr` is lvalue, lvalue reference or rvalue reference, `s` is lvalue reference.
If `expr` is prvalue, it is an error and not legal.

```
auto&& s = expr;
```

`s` is perfectly forwarded (rvalue would become rvalue reference and collapse).