# I'm Returning a Reference From a Lambda, why is a Copy Happening?

Tags: c++, lambda, reference, return, return-type

It's been brought to my attention by the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41487287/2642059) that lambdas I thought were returning by reference are copying. If we define this for example:

```
struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) { cout << "copy\n"; }
};
```

None of this code calls the copy constructor:

```
A a;
const A* pa = &a;
const A& ra = *pa;
```

But this code calls the copy constructor on return:

```
[](const A* pa){ return *pa; }(pa);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/F0EBdm)

I don't get it. Why is it returning by copy? Or more generally I guess I should ask: "How does a lambda decide how to return?"

Comment: Where are you returning a reference?

Comment: Use `[](const A* pa) -> const A& { return *pa; }(pa);` to return by reference.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah that or, `decltype(auto)` was suggested in the original question.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess the question I linked provides a good example, basically the lambda is returning something that is externally owned therefore the copy would be superfluous and wasteful.

Comment: Also see [Is my book's discussion of lamba return types wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14738335), [When can we omit the return type in a C++11 lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955478), [Why do lambda functions drop deduced return type reference by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41534031) and [Explicit Return Type of Lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9620098).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of a lambda is `auto` (`[expr.prim.lambda]/4`), so a copy will be made unless you explicitly specify it with the trailing return type:

```
[](const A* pa) -> const auto& { return *pa; }(pa);
```

Comment: So i guess I should have targeted this question better, cause a copy happens if I do this as well: `const auto ra = *pa` Why is `auto` stripping the reference off my return type? [The built-in indirection operator should return a reference.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_indirection_operator)

Comment: @JonathanMee See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070032/how-does-auto-deduce-type