# How does the auto keyword deduct the type in C++

Tags: c++, variables, types, keyword

I wonder how the auto keyword determines the type of a variable in c++. I thought that statically typed languages couldn't do that.
For example, how does this work:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    auto a = 5433245244524;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The rules for that are in the C++ standard. Check e.g. cppreference.com. It would also help if you told us what is unclear in the above, like e.g. what it does vs. what you would expect.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I just wanted to know why this works. I am trying to understand the 'behind the scenes' behaviour.

Comment: _"...For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be __automatically deduced from its initializer__...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto .  C++ is still statically typed; `auto` just allows the type (of the variable) to be deduced __at compile time__.

Comment: What if you replaced `a` with the value it's initialized with? Do you understand why it works there, i.e. how it finds the right overload of `operator<<`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I saw the link you posted, I understand now, thank you!

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070032/how-does-auto-deduce-type

Comment: why do you think statically typed languages have a problem with that? It is rather the opposite, you always know the type of the initializer, and thats what is used to infer the type of `a`

Comment: `5433245244524` is an integer literal and has type `int` – thus `auto a = 5433245244524;` deduces `a`'s type to be `int` – and that type remains as long as `a` exists. Want an unsigned long instead? Then you need the appropriate literal for, e.g. `auto a = 77UL;`. No appropriate suffix available? Then cast: `auto a = static_cast<uint32_t>(77);` – admitted, in this case `uint32_t a = 77;` is just so much more convenient (OK, `auto a = uint32_t(77);` is fine as well, but less convenient as my preferred variant).

Comment: @Aconcagua Since C++11, an unspecified suffix base 10 number will be promoted to a `long` or `long long` if it does not fit in an `int`.

Comment: @Aconcagua the type of a decimal integer literal will be the smallest fitting among `int`, `long` and `long long`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, [%*&$+!], that bypassed me entirely... Not sure if I should be happy about that change in the standard, though...

Comment: @yoyopi768yoyopi768 Considering my previous comment: In that case the literal is of type `long long` on most platforms (`long` on 64 bit linux as this one has a 64-bit `long`). Rest of the comment still applies (cannot fix any more).

Comment: *I thought that statically typed languages couldn't do that.*  Why do/did you think that?  The ML family of languages have been doing that since the 1970s.  C# has been doing that since C# v3.0 (late 2007).

Comment: Because that is why we always declare the type before the variable. That's what I thought.

Comment: *Because that is why we always declare the type before the variable.*  No, we "always" declare the type before the variable because before 2011 C++ did not support type deduction.  Since 2011, C++ supports type deduction, using [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).  Type deduction was a solved problem for statically typed languages since the 1970s (or earlier; I'm not sure what statically typed language first had type deduction).

Comment: Every expression in C++ has a type. Before `auto` you always have to specify variable type and compiler validated that expression type and variable type are compatible, otherwise you would get compilation error. Since C++11 you can say - just use expression type and assign it to the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works in same way as deduction of expression returning type for templates. It happens at compilation type, so it is a static type.

Literal `5433245244524` comprises  initializing expression. You can get the type of expression at compile time (static type) by using operator `decltype()`. E.g.

```
 decltype(5433245244524) a = 5433245244524;
```

But `auto`keyword is more than that. It's a *placeholder type*. E.g. in statement

```
 const auto& a = 5433245244524;
```

Here `auto` replaces identifier of type without qualifiers to form a compatible reference type.

There is a number of other uses for keyword `auto`, e.g. function's trailing return type, etc. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto